# In which case dimension of eigenspace is greater?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is given problem that says:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space
>   whose characteristic polynomial splits, and let $\lambda$ be an
>   eigenvalue of T. Suppose that $\beta$ is a basis for $K_\lambda$
>   (generalized eigenspace of $\lambda$) consisting of the union of $q$
>   disjoint cycles of generalized eigenvectors. Prove that $q \leq \dim
>  (E_\lambda)$.

I have proved it using the knowing fact that each disjoint cycle has one eigenvector  (which is the last element of each cycle) also they are independent. So from these $q $ cycles we have  $q $ linearly independent eigenvectors of $\lambda $. So my proof is done. (Correct me if I am wrong,I will be happy if anyone give me another approach)

I am interested in those cases where number of disjoint cycles is strictly less than the dimension of eigenspace. I have found such an example:
$$\begin {bmatrix}
1&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
\end {bmatrix} $$
Here the number of disjoint cycles is $2$ which is less than dimension of eigenspace of $1$ which is $3$.

My question is in which case or does there exist any general idea where the nequality holds?

Comment: It's `\lambda` $\lambda$ and `\beta` $\beta$.

Comment: It's `\lambda`, not `\lamda` for $\lambda$, and `\beta`, not `\bita` for $\beta.

Comment: To answer your question, do you know of the Jordan form?

Comment: Yes...I'm studing it

Comment: give space after `$` sign. for $\leq$ write `\leq`